# Frame by frame animation Android

Tags: android, animation, animationdrawable

I wanted to create a talking avatar, using tts Android and drawable frame anmation in Android. The lip sync images were stored in the drawable folder. And this is the piece of function that is executed when the speak button is pressed.

The gist of the function is, based on the letters occurring, each corresponding lip sync action is added to the animation. The rest of actions are based on the language selected to speak, the pitch and speech rate decided. Thread is used to run the animation and the voice parallel.

```
     b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //thread to add the animation
            Thread avatarSp = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
                    String[] words = toSpeak.split(" ");
                    for (String word : words) {
                        word = word.toLowerCase();
                        char[] letters = word.toCharArray();
                        for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                            if (letters[i] == 'a') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a_i), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a_i), 750);
                            } else if (letters[i] == 'e') {
                                if (letters[i + 1] == 'i' || letters[i + 1] == 'a' || letters[i + 1] == 'e') {
                                    i++;
                                    if (sr1 == 1)
                                        avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e), 500);
                                    else if (sr1 == 2)
                                        avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e), 750);
                                } else {
                                    if (sr1 == 1)
                                        avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l), 500);
                                    else if (sr1 == 2)
                                        avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l), 750);
                                }

                            } else if (letters[i] == 'i') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c_d_g_k_n_r_s_th_y_z), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c_d_g_k_n_r_s_th_y_z), 750);

                            } else if (letters[i] == 'o') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.o), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.o), 750);
                            } else if (letters[i] == 'u') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.u), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.u), 750);
                            } else if (letters[i] == 'w' || letters[i] == 'q') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.w_q), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.w_q), 750);
                            } else if (letters[i] == 'f' || letters[i] == 'v') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f_v), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f_v), 750);
                            } else if (letters[i] == 'l') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l), 750);
                            } else if (letters[i] == 'm' || letters[i] == 'b' || letters[i] == 'p') {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m_b_p), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m_b_p), 750);
                            } else {
                                if (sr1 == 1)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c_d_g_k_n_r_s_th_y_z), 500);
                                else if (sr1 == 2)
                                    avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c_d_g_k_n_r_s_th_y_z), 750);
                            }
                        }
                        if (sr1 == 1)
                            avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rest), 500);
                        else if (sr1 == 2)
                            avatarSpeak.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rest), 750);
                    }
                    avatar.post(new Starter());
                }

            });
            //start the thread
            avatarSp.start();
            tts1.setPitch(p1);
            tts1.setSpeechRate(sr1);
            String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
            lang = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (lang.equals("US")) {
                System.out.print("Condition satisfied");
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            } else if (lang.equals("UK"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            else if (lang.equals("Germany"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.GERMANY);
            else if (lang.equals("Italy"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.ITALY);
            else if (lang.equals("Japan"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.JAPAN);
            else
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.CHINA);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //speak
            tts1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                tts1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            } else {
                tts1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The API level in which the whole coded tested was Android 5.0 (21) And Android 6.0 (AVD 23). But when I press the speak button, the API crashes, both on the AVD and Phone. Can you please tell me:

```
    1. Where the error could possibly be?
    2. Is there a better way to do this and how?
```

Please bear with me if its novice, but I would really like to know better ways to do achieve functions, in my own code.

**UPDATE 1**

The log cat info is added.

```
    10-29 09:02:26.245    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    10-29 09:02:26.246    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
    10-29 09:02:26.411    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
    10-29 09:02:27.282    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak-2/lib/x86
    10-29 09:02:28.992    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/TextToSpeech﹕ Sucessfully bound to com.svox.pico
    10-29 09:02:29.026    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    10-29 09:02:29.056    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3fff460, tid 1931
    10-29 09:02:29.300    1931-1938/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 37.049ms
    10-29 09:02:29.459    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa3fff830, tid 1956
    10-29 09:02:29.509    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    10-29 09:02:29.671    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    10-29 09:02:29.672    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad77ac60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    10-29 09:02:29.912    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-29 09:02:31.082    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-29 09:02:31.297    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/TextToSpeech﹕ Connected to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}
    10-29 09:02:31.822    1931-1968/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/TextToSpeech﹕ Set up connection to ComponentInfo{com.svox.pico/com.svox.pico.PicoService}
    10-29 09:02:32.280    1931-1938/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 288.632ms
    10-29 09:02:35.320    1931-1938/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 12.137ms
    10-29 09:02:43.335    1931-2173/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-83
Process: com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak, PID: 1931
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6556)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:942)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5081)
        at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:12713)
        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:12649)
        at android.view.View.invalidateDrawable(View.java:16788)
        at android.widget.ImageView.invalidateDrawable(ImageView.java:248)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.invalidateDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:377)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:385)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setVisible(Drawable.java:764)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.initializeDrawableForDisplay(DrawableContainer.java:510)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:459)
        at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.setFrame(AnimationDrawable.java:274)
        at android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable.addFrame(AnimationDrawable.java:251)
        at com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak.MainActivity$4$1.run(MainActivity.java:190)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    10-29 09:02:44.093    1931-1942/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10741(781KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 1.490ms total 313.129ms
    10-29 09:02:44.122    1931-1942/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 26.447ms
    10-29 09:02:44.278    1931-1938/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 146.147ms
    10-29 09:02:45.073    1931-1931/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    10-29 09:02:45.160    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    10-29 09:02:45.161    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa29586e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    10-29 09:02:45.231    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab81f1e0
    10-29 09:02:47.005    1931-1956/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak E/Surface﹕ getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab81f1e0
    10-29 09:02:48.334    1931-2173/com.bluesbegone.avatarspeak I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1931 SIG: 9
```

Comment: what does logcat show?

Comment: @Chris thank you for your reply. Sorry for not getting back sooner, and please check your edit. Let me know if the data is sufficient.

Comment: @Chris am not able to understand much from the logcat. some directions could be really helpful, for the future as well.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to animate a view from a background thread, but only the main thread can touch views.  Get rid of the thread and just put the code in the main onClick method.

Comment: the thing is I want the animation and the speech to run at the same time. The timing has to be matched. How can I achieve this, if not parallel processing? Can you suggest a better way for the animation I am trying to do?

Comment: Removing the thread helped @Chris. But am facing few more problems.