# Sync between two parallel processes Android

Tags: android, animation, text-to-speech

This is a case of a talking avatar, where the animation and the speech have to sync.

The following code is the onClick function that is invoked when the **speak** button is pressed.

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            avatarSpeak.stop();
            tts1.setPitch(p1);
            tts1.setSpeechRate(sr1);
            String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
            createAnim(toSpeak, sr1);
            lang = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (lang.equals("US")) {
                System.out.print("Condition satisfied");
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            } else if (lang.equals("UK"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            else if (lang.equals("Germany"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.GERMANY);
            else if (lang.equals("Italy"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.ITALY);
            else if (lang.equals("Japan"))
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.JAPAN);
            else
                tts1.setLanguage(Locale.CHINA);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tts1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                tts1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            } else {
                tts1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
            avatarSpeak.start();
        }
    });
```

As you can read the code **avatarSpeak** is the animationDrawable, that plays the animation for the speech. The animation is created, according to the text entered by the **createAnim** function, called in the code. The animation function is called, only after the **speak** function is invoked, to speak the words.

However, when the app is run for the first time, the animation plays first, and after a few seconds delay, the speech occurs. How can this occur, when the speech is invoked, before the animation.?

I could provide more data if required.

Comment: try `tts1.speak` and `avatarSpeak.start();` in separate thread

Comment: tried that and got the error from this question, which I posted earlier. The solution was to remove the thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33359233/frame-by-frame-animation-android

Comment: Put `tts1.speak` inside new thread not `avatarSpeak.start()` because view can only be updated from main thread

Comment: thanks! will try that.